# Set maximizeResourceAllocation=true at EMR cluster level programatically in spark Scala

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I'm trying to find a way to set the maximizeResourceAllocation=true property at the EMR cluster level in spark scala. I used --conf maximizeResourceAllocation=true argument with the spark-submit command but looks like that is not having any effect.

Comment: Why do you think it is not taking any effect?

Comment: My job still failed with same memroy issue

Answer (score 1):

The below code helps to set the configuartion at cluster level

```
 import java.util
 val sparkProperties = new util.HashMap[String, String]
 sparkProperties.put("maximizeResourceAllocation", "true")
 val sparkConfiguration = new Configuration().withClassification("spark").withProperties(sparkProperties)

 new RunJobFlowRequest()
  .withAdditionalInfo(additionalInfoStr)
  .withApplications(spark)
  ...... 
  .withConfigurations(sparkConfiguration)
```